# Changing Remote Git Repository

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to figure out how to change the remote git repository for one of my projects in `Visual Studio 2013`. I know how to set up a remote repository initially, but now that my repository has changed (the location, it is no longer on github), I cannot seem to find any place in the team explorer that allows me to change the remote location that it keeps pushing changes to.

Is there a way to do this without having to remake the entire project?

Comment: Do you have command line git installed? I've found that all the IDE integrated UIs get in the way. This is trivial to fix with the command line tools.

Answer (score 2):

From the command line, run `git remote set-url origin NEWURL`, where `NEWURL` is the new repository address.

If your remote is named something other than `origin`, you can adjust the command accordingly`

Answer (score 0):

You can manually edit the `config` file in your `.git` directory to point to your new location.

Or remove the old one and add a new one with the same name if you don't feel ok with editing the config file by hand.